# Failed to create .cap file using intelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javacard

I'm using maven and intelliJ. I'm trying to create a .cap file from my HelloWorld project for installing my java card but unfortunately when I try to deploy my project, it gives me an error:

> "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on
>   project helloworld: An Ant BuildException has occured: Java returned:
>   1 -> [Help 1]".

In addition, the compile procedure is succeeded and it does not give any error.

I can not find out what is the problem though I have downloaded and updated all the necessary packages of intelliJ. These packages are offered by intelliJ.

I would be grateful if any one can help me to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.sourceforge.globalplatform.jc</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Hello World Java Card Applet</name>


    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Karsten Ohme</name>
            <id>k_o_</id>
            <email>k_o_@users.sourceforge.net</email>
            <roles>
                <role>Developer</role>
            </roles>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <properties>
                <sourcedirectory>src/main/java</sourcedirectory>
                <javacard.applet.name>HelloWorldApplet</javacard.applet.name>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jc.home>${env.JC_HOME}</jc.home>
        <javacard.package.name>net.sourceforge.globalplatform.jc.helloworld</javacard.package.name>
        <javacard.package.aid>0xD0:0xD1:0xD2:0xD3:0xD4:0xD5:0x01</javacard.package.aid>
        <javacard.applet.aid>0xD0:0xD1:0xD2:0xD3:0xD4:0xD5:0x01:0x02</javacard.applet.aid>
        <javacard.major.version>1</javacard.major.version>
        <javacard.minor.version>0</javacard.minor.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacard</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/java_card_kit-2_2_2/lib/api.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${sourcedirectory}</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Convert to cap file -->
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo message="Converting to CAP file" />
                        <java classname="com.sun.javacard.converter.Converter"
                            failonerror="true" fork="true">
                            <arg value="-verbose" />
                            <arg value="-classdir" />
                            <arg value="target/classes/" />
                            <arg value="-applet" />
                            <arg value="${javacard.applet.aid}" />
                            <arg value="${javacard.applet.name}" />
                            <arg value="${javacard.package.name}" />
                            <arg value="${javacard.package.aid}" />
                            <arg value="${javacard.major.version}.${javacard.minor.version}" />
                            <arg value="-nowarn" />
                            <classpath>
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/api21_export_files" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/apduio.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/apdutool.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/jcwde.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/converter.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/scriptgen.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/offcardverifier.jar" />
                                <pathelement location="${jc.home}/lib/capdump.jar" />
                            </classpath>
                        </java>
                        <copy todir="target/">
                            <flattenmapper />
                            <fileset dir="target/classes/">
                                <include name="**/*.cap" />
                            </fileset>
                        </copy>
                        <echo message="Transforming for Cyberflex"/>
                        <java jar="${jc.home}/lib/captransf.jar"
                            failonerror="true" fork="true">
                            <arg value="${jc.home}/api21_export_files/java/lang/javacard/lang.exp" />
                            <arg value="${jc.home}/api21_export_files/javacard/framework/javacard/framework.exp" />
                            <arg value="${jc.home}/api21_export_files/javacard/security/javacard/security.exp" />
                            <arg value="${jc.home}/api21_export_files/java/lang/javacard/lang.exp" />
                            <arg value="-s" />
                            <arg value="-noint" />
                            <arg value="target/${project.artifactId}.cap" />
                        </java>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.2</source>
                    <target>1.1</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences-->
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand> org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder </buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <projectnatures>
                        <projectnature> org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature </projectnature>
                    </projectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer> org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
                        </classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: could you show the pom for the project

Comment: yes I edited my question.

Comment: try updating this `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>` to
 `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>`

Comment: It shows the error:
"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project helloworld: An Ant BuildException has occured: Java returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<java fork="true" classname="com.sun.javacard.converter.Converter" failonerror="true">... @ 5:89 in C:\Users\user\Desktop\wallet_pin_puk_trng\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]"

Comment: make sure this exists : `<systemPath>C:/java_card_kit-2_2_2/lib/api.jar</systemPath>`

Comment: Oh, thanks.
this is the problem.
my api21 in pom.xml should be changed to api...!
thank you nullpointer

Comment: now I have another problem!

when I try to install the .cap into the card by GPShell it errors while progressing: 
"load() returns 0x80206985 (6985: Command not allowed - Conditions of use not sat
isfied.)"
does it support java card kit 2.2.2?

Comment: maven was okay for me, can't understand much of .cap..maybe another thread should have it

Comment: how can i install cap file made by java card kit 2.2.2 using GPShell?

Comment: You need to have the GP keys. If the card is in operational state you may need to use command MAC after INITIALIZE UPDATE / EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE.

Comment: What kind of tool do you use to upload your cap files on your card?

Comment: `GPShell` is a really old tool. you can use `PyAPDU` or `GlobalPlatformPro` instead. I posted required links in this post (It's in Persian): http://ebrah1m.blog.ir/1394/07/20/JumpIntoJC-5

Comment: As Mr Bodewes mentioned in his comment, you need to authenticate yourself to the card. Authentication keys for almost all smart cards is `404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f` by default. (For some Gemalto cards it has another value). If you have a fresh smart card, try above keys to authenticate. Note that, 10 wrong tries on authentication will terminate your card (And this event is irreversible)

Comment: And for your information, if you want to reply to somebody's comment under your post, use "@" mark before his name in order to notify him/her with a notification in his/her inbox.(Normally, without "@" mark, they won't notified that you replied to their comment). Good luck bro :)

Comment: @Abraham Thank you for all your kind tips and guides, I've written applets before on java card kit 2.1.2, my problem was to migrate to 2.2.1. my problem solved and thank you again.